# Как создать виртуальный сервер для Magento 2?

Tags: база-данных, хостинг, magento

Возникла необходимость создать эмулятор сервера, отвечающий требованиям новой *CMS* *Magento 2* для обучения. Так как ничего подобного никогда не делал, прошу направить в нужном направлении дабы избежать неверных попыток и потери времени.

*Magento* требуется следующее программное обеспечение для запуска:
Веб-сервер: *Apache 2.2* или *2.4*
Язык программирования: *PHP 5.6.x* или *5.5.x*
База данных: *MySQL 5.6.x*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то Вам нужно не сервер эмулировать, а создать среду где можно развернуть ваши учебные приложения.

Для этих целей используются `WAMP`-сборки (акроним от «*Windows*, *Apache*, *MySQL* и *PHP*») подробнее [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP), сравнение [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144242/).

Если коротко то это комплексное решение с предустановленным и настроенным по умолчанию базовым пакетом необходимых программ.

От себя могу порекомендовать *XAMPP*, подробнее [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)